# Populate a combobox in DropButtonClick

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate a combobox as it is needed, by doing the population in the DropButtonClick function. As a simple example:

```
Private Sub cmbAdvisor_DropButtonClick()
    cmbAdvisor.Clear

    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test1")
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test2")
End Sub
```

This works fine, and the values are shown in the drop down list. However, when I click on one of them, the drop down list goes away, and the combobox now displays nothing/blank. I would expect it to display the item that I had selected. I'm guessing the problem is that I am doing a Clear inside of this function - but how else would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using the `DropButtonClick` event. Here is an alternative (**WAY 1**) but if you still want to use `DropButtonClick` then see **WAY 2**

**Way 1**

You can populate the combobox either in the `UserForm_Initialize()` or a button click event. For example

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test1")
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test2")
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    cmbAdvisor.Clear
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test1")
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test2")
End Sub
```

**Way 2**

If you still want to populate the combobox in `DropButtonClick` then use this

```
Private Sub cmbAdvisor_DropButtonClick()
    Dim prevPos As Long
    '~~> Get the position of current selection
    prevPos = cmbAdvisor.ListIndex
    
    '~~> Switch off event so that when we select an
    '~~> item, it doesn't run this proc again
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    cmbAdvisor.Clear
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test1")
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test2")
    
    '~~> Set the selected value
    cmbAdvisor.ListIndex = prevPos
    
    '~~> Reset events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an ActiveX control embedded on a sheet:

The activeX combobox processes the click event on item selection as if it were an actual dropbuttonclick - which means we need a state object.

```
Dim dropbuttonclicked As Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
  dropbuttonclicked = Not dropbuttonclicked
  If dropbuttonclicked = True Then
    ComboBox1.Clear
    ComboBox1.AddItem ("Test1")
    ComboBox1.AddItem ("Test2")
  End If
End Sub
```

For a VBA ComboBox on a VBA UserForm, you might want to use `Enter` instead:

```
Private Sub cmbAdvisor_Enter()
    cmbAdvisor.Clear
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test1")
    cmbAdvisor.AddItem ("Test2")
End Sub
```

Comment: Enter does not seem to be a choice of valid functions in the drop down list in the VB editor (and I tried it anyway, and it is indeed not triggered). I looked at the Click function, but it doesn't seem to be triggered until I click on one of the items in the combo box (not during the initial "drop down" click).

Comment: I am in Excel 2010. I do see DropButtonClick, but the next item is Error.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you... :). I added an ActiveX combobox to the sheet, and then in the VB editor, the list of available functions is as I said. Is this the same procedure you used?

Comment: @DavidDoria did you try GotFocus? That worked for me when I embedded an activex combobox on a sheet.

Comment: GotFocus produces even weirder results. When I click the combobox, sometimes the list shows up like normal. Other times the list shows up as only one line with little tiny scroll buttons (more like a list box than combobox). Other times there are worse/strange rendering artifacts (like the box is kind of drawn but not quite). I'm guess that this again is due to the .Clear call at the beginning of the function?

Comment: I really want the .clear call to be ok. You might want to shore up the function with a bunch of lines setting the combo's properties again, in code, each time... nail it down, as it were - but really? I added the monitor object and went back to dropdownclick, once again it-works-on-my-machine...